# Display multiple images in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of image locations

```
image_locations = [path/car.jpg, path/tree.jpg, ..., path/apple.jpg]
```

Each image has a different size and shape.

What is the best way to display/print these images (ideally in some grid) in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modules `pyplot`, `image` and then the function `subplots()`:

```
# Import modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# Read images
img1 = mpimg.imread('myImage1.png')
img2 = mpimg.imread('myImage2.png')
img3 = mpimg.imread('myImage3.png')
img4 = mpimg.imread('myImage4.png')

# Set your canvas (fig) and the number of axes (images) you want to display
# In this example I want to display my 4 images in a grid 2x2

fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(15,10))

ax1.imshow(img1)
ax1.set_title("Image 1")
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.set_title("Image 2")
ax3.imshow(img3)
ax3.set_title("Image 3")
ax4.imshow(img4)
ax4.set_title("Image 4")

plt.show()

# The same example with just the first two images in a grid 1x2

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(15,10))

ax1.imshow(img1)
ax1.set_title("Image 1")
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.set_title("Image 2")

plt.show()
```

`Fig` is just a container of your `axes`.

Comment: Works, great! Thanks.